# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Tags: php, parsing, magento, syntax, public

I changed something in my "redirect base url" options on the magento admin page. However, that  didnt work out that well. After that I got the following error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in ..../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 662**

With the code:

```
public function setNode($path, $value, $overwrite = true)
{
    if ($this->_useCache && ($path !== null)) {
        $sectionPath = explode('/', $path);
        $config = $this->_getSectionConfig($sectionPath);
        if ($config) {
            $sectionPath = array_slice($sectionPath, $this->_cacheSections[$sectionPath[0]]+1);
            $sectionPath = implode('/', $sectionPath);
            $config->setNode($sectionPath, $value, $overwrite);
        }
    }
    return parent::setNode($path, $value, $overwrite);
}
```

I cannot figure out the problem myself as Im a rookie with this kind of stuff. Could anybody perhaps help me out?:)

Comment: Please show what's on the line before.

Answer (score 16):

I had same problem with my code when I was working in an Opencart Project. 
After several hours of frustration I realized that the cause of this issue was the absence of closure of last function.

I forgot to close the function above it i.e. 
 `}`
was missing so it was like defining a function inside another function. Have you checked if that's the same case with you.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem in my case too. You save me hours of hair pulling. :P

Comment: This was the same problem with me also. @elembivos I have to admit and "facepalming" myself that I "should' have popped someone else's code that I tested into my editor "before" running it *lol*. Oh well, nobody's  perfect ;-) Gotta love Google, eh?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use this in a class, or remove the `public` word.

Comment: I already tried removing the public word. Then it asks me to remove all the public words in the whole file. Doin that leaves me still what an error. I can provide you with the code if that might help, because I have no clue what it could be :$

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly an error in your code, and this is exactly why you should not edit core files as you have here.

You can copy the file you hanged into the local name space from 'core' and then copy the original Magento file back over the core version.

This will allow you to revert easily if you make a mistake.

I would also recommend to get a decent IDE which will show u any coding errors such as missing brackets etc. try something like netbeans or eclipse for excellent warnings when u make simple mistakes